# Prove that $ABC$ is equilateral

Tags: geometry

Let $D,E,F$ be points on the sides BC,CA,AB respectively of a triangle $ABC$  such that $BD=CE=AF$ and $\angle BDF=\angle CED=\angle AFE$.Prove that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.

My attempt - Using sine rule in triange $\triangle AFE$ ,$\triangle EDC$ and $\triangle BFD$ respectively, we have $AE \sin\angle AEF=BF \sin\angle BFD=DC\sin\angle FDC $.

But that does not help much.I am totally unaware what to do.please help.

Comment: Did you mean $\angle AFE$ rather than $\angle AFG$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant $\angle AFE $

Comment: I just notice that you see my solution as unclear. I do that on purpose as this is a learning site. Anyhow, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: @Quang Hoang I m really sorry for that but could u plz tell me what does WLOG stand for and what does ∠D1=min{∠D1,∠E1,∠F1} mean.once again I m very sorry

Comment: Without Lost Of Generality. And $D1$ means the angle at $D$ containing number $1$ in picture. $D1=\min\{\}$ means $D1$ is the smallest angle among those.

Comment: @Quang Hoang And how can we say that∠D1=min{∠D1,∠E1,∠F1}.Can u also plz tell how does it follows from this that ∠C is the largest angle of △ABC.

Comment: Because $D2=\max\{D2,E2F2\}$, and sum of three angles at $D$ is $180^\circ$. Then look at the three corner triangles for the last argument. Now that I think about it. $\angle C =\angle D2$, and the conclusion follows faster.

Comment: @Quang Hoang One last question, how can we say D2=max{D2,E2,F2}.

Comment: Because as the second picture showed, $EF$ is larger than any other side of $\triangle DEF$.

Comment: @Quang Hoang And how is EF larger than the others?

Comment: See the second picture. If we stack up the three corner triangles, then the one with the largest angle among $A,B,C$ has the largest opposite side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So one has the following settings

[image]

WLOG, assume that $A$ is the max angle in $\triangle ABC$. It follows from the picture below that $EF$ is the largest side of $\triangle DEF$.

[image]

That means $\angle D2$ is the largest angle in $\triangle DEF$. We have
$$\angle D1=\min\{\angle D1,\angle E1,\angle F1\}.$$
This follows that $\angle C$ is the largest angle of $\triangle ABC$, or that $\angle C=\angle A$.

P/S: Please excuse my hand-drawing. I was too lazy for computer graphics.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. why is $\angle AEF = \angle BFD$?

Comment: @DigitalBrain I didn't use that in the proof. The notation $\angle E1$ stands for $\angle AEF$ (to distinguish from $\angle E2=\angle DEF$).

Comment: But you marked some angles with blue sign.

Comment: @DigitalBrain Sure, you can say that it's bad notations. But that the three angles are equal is a by-product of the problem (the three corner triangles are congruent by ASA).

Comment: Why can one say that $\triangle DEF$ is equilateral?

Comment: @RainiervanEs: See my last comment about the three corner triangles.